# Attempting to encrypt existing PVs in EKS

Tags: encryption, kubernetes

I'm attempting to encrypt our existing PVs in EKS. Basically been searching the net and haven't come up with a solid solution. Our K8s version is 1.11 on EKS. Our PVs are EBS volumes. We currently have account level ebs encryption enabled but didn't when these resources were made.

I attempted to stop the ASG and the node. Created a snapshot and new encrypted volume then ran:

```
kubectl patch pv pvc-xxxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxxxx -p '{"spec":{"awsElasticBlockStore":{"volumeID":"aws://us-east-1b/vol-xxxxx"}}}'
```

but was met with:

```
The PersistentVolume is invalid: spec.persistentvolumesource: Forbidden: is immutable after creation
```

I'm looking for a solution to this issue or to validate that is in fact not possible. Potential relevant github issue:
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/59642

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have exactly the same needs... There are two options that I think are possible but haven't tried them yet. The 1st one would be to copy the content on a new encrypted and empty EBS that would be created by k8s PV. The second would be to create a storageclasse and a new PV with the full encrypted EBS ID and attach the all to the pod or pod controller.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this issue or still on going ?